# How to lift to Servant Server type?

Tags: haskell, servant

I am having problems with following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module API where

import           Data.Text
import           Servant.API
import           Servant
import           Repository 
import           FileOperation
import           Util
import           Config
import qualified Data.Map                   as M
import           Control.Monad.State.Strict (liftIO)
import           Network.Wai.Handler.Warp

type RepositoryAPI = "repository" :> "all" :> Get '[JSON] [Repository] 
                :<|> "all" :> "repository" :> Get '[JSON] [Repository]

server :: Server RepositoryAPI
server = do
  repositoriesMap <- liftIO $ loadFromFile repositoryMapFile
  let repositories = M.elems repositoriesMap in do
    return repositories 

repositoryAPI :: Proxy RepositoryAPI 
repositoryAPI = Proxy

app :: Application
app = serve repositoryAPI server

main :: IO ()
main = run 8081 app
```

The error I get is:

```
API.hs:22:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘Handler [Repository]’
      Expected type: Server RepositoryAPI
        Actual type: Handler [Repository] :<|> [a0]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        repositoriesMap <- liftIO $ loadFromFile repositoryMapFile
      In the expression:
        do repositoriesMap <- liftIO $ loadFromFile repositoryMapFile
           let repositories = ... in do return repositories
      In an equation for ‘server’:
          server
            = do repositoriesMap <- liftIO $ loadFromFile repositoryMapFile
                 let ... in do ...
   |
22 |   repositoriesMap <- liftIO $ loadFromFile repositoryMapFile
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The question is how do I lift properly so that the lift returns Servant Server type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with lifting. The real problem is that you only specified one `Handler`, but your server needs two `Handler`s, one for `"repository" :> "all" :> Get '[JSON] [Repository]` and one for `"all" :> "repository" :> Get '[JSON] [Repository]`. Here's a skeleton for your second one (replace your existing `server` with this):

```
getRepositoryAll :: Handler [Repository]
getRepositoryAll = do
  repositoriesMap <- liftIO $ loadFromFile repositoryMapFile
  let repositories = M.elems repositoriesMap in do
    return repositories 

getAllRepository :: Handler [Repository]
getAllRepository = undefined -- fill this in

server :: Server RepositoryAPI
server = getRepositoryAll :<|> getAllRepository
```